# How to tune Oracle's SQL*Loader append?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am writing a Java program that creates a CSV file with 6,800,000 records conforming to specific distribution parameters and populates a table using Oracle's SQL*Loader.

I am testing my program using different sizes of records (50,000 and 500.000). The CSV File generation by itself is quite fast, using concurrency it takes miliseconds to create and insert these records into a file.

Inserting said records, on the other hand, is taking too long. Reading the log file generated by SQL*Loader, it takes 00:00:32.90 seconds to populate the table with 50,000 records and 00:07:58.83 minutes to populate it with 500,000.

SQL*Loader benchmarks I've googled show much better perfomances, such as 2 million rows in less than 2 minutes. I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_optimize_sql_loader_sqlldr_performance.htm) to improve the time, but it barely changed at all. There's obviously something wrong here, but I don't know what.

Here's my control file:

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=ALL, DIRECT=TRUE, ERRORS=50, COLUMNARRAYROWS=50000, STREAMSIZE=500000)
UNRECOVERABLE LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
...
```

Another important info: I've tried using PARALLEL=TRUE, but I get the ORA-26002 error (Table MY_TABLE has index defined upon it). Unfortunatly, running with skip_index_maintenance renders the index UNUSABLE.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

I have noticed that soon after running the program (less than a second), all rows are already present in the database. Yet, SQL*Loader is still busy and only finishes after 32-45 seconds.

What could it be doing?

Answer (score 1):

One thought would be to create an external table and set the name to the csv file. Then after creating the file you can run a sql script inside Oracle to process the data directly.

Or, look at the following (copied from [here](http://sajid-arshad.blogspot.com/2010/04/ora-26002-table-has-index-defined-upon.html):)

This issue is caused when using the bulk load option in parallel to load an Oracle target that has an index on it. An Oracle limitation.

To resolve this issue do one of the following:

· Change the target load option to Normal.

· Disable the enable parallel mode option in relational connection browser.

· Drop the indexes before loading.

· Or create a pre- and post-session sql to drop and create indexes and key constraints

Comment: good one... droping and recreating the index is not an option, I'll try with conventional insert...

Comment: conventional path took way more time... I guess the problem lies within the table or database used, I'll ask a DBA to take a look.